# jquery replace charactor and start and end

Tags: javascript, jquery

i can getting one dynamic string in my code. i am using jquery to replace additional " at start and end.
 But some time i get  'My Name' and Some times it returns 'My Name' and some cases i am not sure how many ' are before and after the string.

in Some cases i got '' My' Name' so result i want is My' Name

How can i remove the all  ' before and after string

```js
  var UserDepartment="''''My Name'";//JSON.stringify(k.Value);
 UserDepartment=UserDepartment.replace('"','');
  $("#result").html(UserDepartment);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply change your replace from this

```
replace('"','');
```

to this

```
replace(/^["']+|["']+$/g,'');
```

- `^` - Start of string.
- `["']+` - Match `"` or `'` one or more time.
- `|` - Alternation same as logical OR.
- `$` - End of string.

```js
var UserDepartment="''''My' Name'";//JSON.stringify(k.Value);
 UserDepartment=UserDepartment.replace(/^["']+|["']+$/g,'');
  $("#result").html(UserDepartment);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the parameters of replace() method in the code as follows:-

```
UserDepartment=UserDepartment.replace(/'/g,"");
```

It will work fine. Thanks!